# How do I set the default application for xdg-open on a callto: or skype: URL?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, skype

I'm writing a Chrome extension which links phone numbers in the page so you can click them and make a Skype call.

Chrome on Linux uses `xdg-open` to delegate external URL handling, and it doesn't understand `callto:` or `skype:` URLs. I know that if I can figure out the appropriate mime-type I can use `xdg-mime default` to set Skype as the handler, but I've searched and can't find anything on the topic.

How can I set this up so that `xdg-open callto:+1234567890`, for instance, will place a call using Skype?

Comment: I don't believe you can - can you register a bug on http://crbug.com/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Skype needs to register a custom protocol on Linux. Then xdg-open will know what do do with `callto`. You might try asking in the [Skype Linux](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showforum=18) forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jaro](https://github.com/isamert/jaro) to handle this use case. Here is jaro example to run youtube links, but I believe that you can customize it for your usecase

```
(assoc
  #:pattern "^https?://.*"
  #:program "qutebrowser %f"
  #:test "pgrep qutebrowser"
  #:on-fail "firefox %f")
```